# Which NPCs can point me to San Francisco?

Tags: fallout-2

I want to travel to San Francisco. Unfortunately it's been a long time and I forgot where it is and people in other towns don't want to tell me. I have asked for directions and got plenty, but none of them to that great city. My question is in what cities can I find out how to get to San Francisco (also which NPCs will tell me)?

I would like a complete list (it shouldn't be long) so I can decide which cities to stop in to get directions.

I would like to know what people will actually put San Francisco on my map, rather than the actual directions of how to get there on the map.

Comment: thanks but those are actual directions of how to get there. I would like to know npcs that will place San Francisco on my map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Having [San Francisco](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/San_Francisco) revealed on your map can only happen right before you get there**, oddly enough. In the [The Military Base](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mariposa_Military_Base), you will find a [Survey Map](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Survey_map) held in [a footlocker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYLtn.jpg) in [one of the outter tents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYLtn.jpg) that will reveal San Francisco's location after using it. Geographically, this is very close to San Francisco, so having it revealed at this stage isn't  terribly useful.

If you want to know which cities to visit, I would suggest that [NCR (New California Republic)](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/New_California_Republic) should be the last city that you visit before trekking out to San Francisco.

To clear up any confusion, there are a few NPC's which will mention San Francisco beforehand, however they will not reveal it on the map:

- **[Doc Holliday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxOl8.jpg)** in Broken Hills tells you a story about San Francisco. You can relay this story to the doctor in San Francisco, but this will not reveal San Francisco's location.
- **[Brotherhood of Steel's NCR outpost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEMDO.jpg)** will tell you to visit their San Francisco outpost if you pass a level check, however this will not reveal San Francisco's location.
- **[The Hubologist in NCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0K0Q.jpg)** will give you [a letter](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Enlightened_One%27s_letter) to deliver to San Francisco if you manage to pass a speech check, but this also will not reveal San Francisco on your map.

**SPOILERS / DIRECTIONS BELOW:** (mouse over to reveal)

> If you are following the general path that the game is intended to be played out in (see image below), you will likely come upon New Reno or Broken Hills. Moving on from there, you will likely travel South to NCR. From NCR, you travel West until you hit The Military Base, and then San Francisco.
>  [image: a map of Fallout 2 with directions to get to San Francisco]
> Alternatively, you could simply leave from Arroyo (where you start the game) and head straight South to San Francisco, saving often to avoid being killed by random encounters.

**Final notes:**

- If you are going to play through Fallout 2, I highly recommend installing the [Fallout 2 Resoration Project 2.1.2b](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=811799). It fixes many problems with the game (including technical problems on modern systems) as well as adding additional content should you desire it.
- Refer to **[this guide](https://lemmings19.github.io/fallout-2-walkthrough/)** if you need any help. Use the search function to find keywords. Everything in the game is in there.
- If you are using the [Restoration Project](http://www.nma-fallout.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=811799), refer to **[this guide](http://hem.bredband.net/darek1/f2rp_wt.htm)** for additional help.

Comment: Excellent answer. I am going through Fallout 2 restoration project :) (in fact its the reason why im playing the game over again) Do any of the NPC reveal san francisco in the restoration project??

Comment: Afraid not. The closest you can get is a random encounter which will show you where The Military Base is located: http://falloutmods.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_2_Restoration_Project_guide_-_New_areas#A_Traveler:

Comment: Also, if you're going through the restoration project, hit up Myron outside of New Reno. He (or he Traveler) can tell you how to find The EPA; an entirely new location added in the patch. There is also a new location added in the top right of the map (NE of Gecko) called The Abbey. Finally, South of Arroyo is a new Primitive Tribe location which Sulik can tell you about. Enjoy the patch, and don't forget to up your screen resolution via the Options menu! (look for "SCRN" at the top)

Comment: @Xitcod13 I added two more notes containing two of the most complete guides that you can find for Fallout 2. Use them if you need help! Any information should be in there.

Comment: wow i didnt even know about the resolution option. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not a problem. I suppose it's a good thing that I pointed it out! I know that it's sort of hidden off to the side, so I figured it was easy to miss. I didn't expect to still be playing this game 16 years after it came out and I was just a kid. 16 years. Wow, that's scary! lol

Comment: Yes one of the best turn based RPGs ever. :) If only there were more levels perks and places.

Answer (score 1):

I have a great memory about Fallout. As I remember and as my small pleasant search shows, you can receive location of San Francisco in only 2 ways:

1. Map in the Mariposa Military Base
2. Chris in Navarro

But in its turn about Mariposa Military Base you can learn also in two ways:

1. Goris in Vault 13
2. Chris in Navarro (again)

And about Navarro you can know only after returning to Arroyo with GECK.

So there's no fair way to get the location of San Francisco during the first 3/4 of the game. And if I were developer, I would make locations of this three places hidden - that it was not possible to get there before you receive their locations explicitly. I'm sure that this would make game more interesting. IMHO, walk to San Francisco in the beginning of the game is dull cheating!

Comment: Regarding Chris: `You can get him to mention both San Francisco and the Military Base, but he won't put any of them on your world map.` source: https://lemmings19.github.io/fallout-2-walkthrough/#navarro

Comment: It is very difficult to believe that there's only one way to know about San Francisco (from Military Base) and only one way to know about Military Base (from Goris). In such case, if Chosen One hurry to leave Vault 13 without detailed conversation with Goris, then Goris will be killed during Enclave invasion and Chosen One will be without path to go. In 1998 not many people had Internet to ask help.

Comment: @MalvinaPushkova Fallout 2 doesn't work that way.  You can kill every NPC you come across and still beat the game.  It's VERY well made.

Comment: @Nelson Then name other ways to find these places.
(I'm still think that Chris mention them, but don't have opportunity to check.)